# fetch data from one mongodb collection in multiple projects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hapi.js

I have two projects in `hapiJS` and `mongoDB`. One is for **admin user** and another for **normal user**. I am trying to access a db collection from **admin user** which is defined in the **normal user**. The following error is generated when I run the project

```
{ MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Category". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at new MissingSchemaError (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gg-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/missingSchema.js:22:11)
    at Mongoose.model (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gg-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gg-admin/app/helpers/dashboard.js:7:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gg-admin/app/controllers/web/dashboard.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)   message: 'Schema hasn\'t been registered for model "Category".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)',   name: 'MissingSchemaError' }
```

my controller :

```
exports.showAllCategory = {
    description: 'returns all caregories',
    auth: {
        mode: 'try',
        strategy: 'standard'

    },

    handler: async (request,h) => {
        try {
            if (request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
                var userDetails = request.auth.credentials;
                let category = await dashboardHelper.fetchAllCatogeryItems();
                if (category.statusCode === 200) {
                    return h.view('dashboard/dashboard', {user: userDetails, categoryData: category.categoryData});
                }                 
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return h.redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    }
};
```

and my db actions are at following `helper.js` file :

```
'use strict';

const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Category = Mongoose.model('Category');
const Joi = require('joi');

exports.fetchAllCatogeryItems = async() =>{
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>{
        try {
            let category = await Category.find();
            if (categoryData) {
                return resolve({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    categoryData: category
                })

            } else {
                statusCode: 400
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return reject(error)
        }
    });
};
```

I have connected the MONGO_URL environment for both apps to point at the same mongodb, and can access the `models` defined within **admin user module**

> I know that my code won't work as my `Category` model has defined in
>   **normal user** and trying to access at **admin user**

Is it possible to access the models defined in **normal user** project somebody ?? Please help me to find a solution for this problem . I have wasted almost 2 days for this.
also I am not experienced in `nodejs` (`hapijs`)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this npm package [The official MongoDB driver for Node.js.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) for querying your mongodb without defining the schema.I hope it will help.